# Passing SQL function parameters

Tags: sql, function, parameters

I have made an SQL function that calculates different data and it looks something like this:

```
Declare @parameter1 float, @parameter2 float, @parameter3 float, @parameter4 float

SET @parameter1 = 3
SET @parameter1 = 5
SET @parameter1 = 7
SET @parameter1 = 9

dbo.SqlFuntion(@parameter1, @parameter2, @parameter3, @parameter4)
```

Now this works just fine, my challenge is that I want my parameters to be retrieved from a database table instead of declaring them manually.

So I want something like:

```
 Select name, age, postal, weight from TableValues where ID = 1234 

 dbo.SqlFuntion(name, age, postal, weight)
```

Can anyone tell me how this can be done, without declaring anything?

Comment: Why not just pass the ID to the function and put the query inside it?

Comment: Without declaring `anything` this is going to be tough, if you insist on not declaring variables you need to put value selection logic into the function itself; though it may very well be you will need to declare variables there then - but that largely depends on what you do with those values exactly in your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Declare @parameter1 float, @parameter2 float, @parameter3 float, @parameter4 float

Select @parameter1 = name, @parameter2 = age, @parameter3 = postal, @parameter4 = weight
from TableValues where ID = 1234 

dbo.SqlFuntion(@parameter1, @parameter2, @parameter3, @parameter4)
```

Comment: You're still declaring :P

Comment: @Rachcha if you want to pass parameters to your function you need to declare them first; the syntax in the original question is flawed - this answer shows how you can assign values to variables via a query; if you do not want to declare extra variables you would need to make your function interacting with that table directly (i.e. executing a very similar select to retrieve the values to work with)

Comment: Thanks mate!, I will try this aswell and get back to u soon!

Comment: Sorry for the late accept, but i just got it working! thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

// YOU CAN DO IT USING CURSOR, IT COULD HELP YOU

```
DECLARE v_done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE v_name VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE v_age DOUBLE;
DECLARE v_postal VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE v_weight DOUBLE;

DECLARE cur1_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT name, age, postal, weight from TableValues where ID = 1234 ;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_done = TRUE;

OPEN cur1_cursor;
    read_loop: LOOP

        FETCH cur1_cursor INTO v_name,v_age,v_postal,v_weight;

        IF v_done THEN
          LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        SET @v_name = v_name;
        SET @v_age = v_age;
        SET @v_postal = v_postal;
        SET @v_weight = v_weight;

        dbo.SqlFuntion(@v_name, @v_age, @v_postal, @v_weight);  

END LOOP;
```

Comment: doing this with a cursor is just obfuscating the hell out of a simple `SELECT @parameter = column FROM TABLE`, besides that what's the benefit? xD

Comment: its depends upon requirement and your choice, its just another way to do this.

Comment: Thanks alot i will try your example and i will get back to u with a feedback!